# How to focus on a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After my user enters text into a form field I want to force the cursor to jump to the next field, by doing something like

```
$('#senderName').focus();
```

This works as long as the next field is an `input` element.  It doesn't work when the next input is a `textarea`. Is there any way to force the cursor to jump  to a `textarea`?

Thanks

Comment: If it works with an input, it should work with a textarea, you'll have reproduce the issue in jsFiddle so we can see it ?

Comment: It should work can you share some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me!

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GeZep/)

```
<textarea id="myid"></textarea>

$("#myid").focus()
```

Comment: Yes, I can't get it to fail either in a jsfiddle. That forced me to look closer at my own code, where I found that I had a second ID with the same name as the id of the textarea I was trying to send focus to. Renaming that fixed the problem. Thanks for the dialog!

Answer (score 0):

Add `tabindex=1` to `textarea`.

```
<textarea id="senderName" tabindex="1"></textarea>
```